# Adding Grouped Dataframes

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have two dataframes. I like the to add add the values in the columns together if the grouping is the same. Doing this with a simple addition works great as long as both group values are in each table. If they are not, it returns `nan`. I am assuming because you can't add `nan` and an `int`, but not sure how to work around this.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['A', 4],
                        ['A', 1],
                        ['B', 1],
                        ['B', 5]],
                   columns=['Person', 'Days'])

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=[['A', 5],
                        ['A', 0],
                        ['C', 3],
                        ['C', 5]],
                   columns=['Person', 'Days'])

df['Days'] = df['Days'] <= 3
df1['Days'] = df1['Days'] <= 3

df = df.groupby('Person').agg(['count'])
df1 = df1.groupby('Person').agg(['count'])

print df + df1
```

Actual Output:

```
        Days
       count
Person      
A          4
B        NaN
C        NaN
```

Desired Output:

```
        Days
       count
Person      
A          4
B          2
C          2
```

Comment: Just replace your last line with: df.add(df1, fill_value=0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

```
In [40]: funcs = ['count','sum']

In [41]: df.groupby('Person').agg(funcs).add(df1.groupby('Person').agg(funcs), fill_value=0)
Out[41]:
        Days
       count sum
Person
A        4.0   2
B        2.0   1
C        2.0   1
```

**Old answer:**

```
In [14]: df.groupby('Person').size().to_frame('count').add(
   ....:  df1.groupby('Person').size().to_frame('count'), fill_value=0)
Out[14]:
        count
Person
A         4.0
B         2.0
C         2.0
```

PS I worked with original DFs - i didn't execute this code :

```
df = df.groupby('Person').agg(['count'])
df1 = df1.groupby('Person').agg(['count'])
```

Comment: thank you. Why won't the `to_frame` method take a list? For example if I wanted to grab `sum` and `count`...`df.groupby('Person').size().to_frame(['sum', 'count']).add(df1.groupby('Person').size().to_frame(['sum', 'count']), fill_value=0)`

Comment: @user2242044, do you want to calculate the `sum` of True/False column? Can you update your question with a desired output?

Comment: yes, in addition to the `count`. Accidentally over simplified my question :)